# How to change URL Suffix of .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

How can I have the following route:

`http://localhost:4413/abc/`

And the following route:

`http://localhost:4413/abc.html`

both return the same controller method, using .NET Core MVC?

Comment: Check the docs ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x url rewrite is the keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want two suffixes to reach the same controller action.

1. an empty suffix
2. an `.html` suffix

Here is one way to do that in your [`Startup.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-startup-class) method. Edit its `app.UseMvc` to look like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    // this is the default route that is already present
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // map the empty suffix
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "home",
        template: "{action}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Home" });

    // map the .html suffix
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "home.html",
        template: "{action}.html",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Home" });
});
```

Now, both routes will reach the same controller method.

```
http://localhost:4413/abc/      -->  HomeController.Abc()
http://localhost:4413/abc.html  -->  HomeController.Abc()
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#special-case-for-dedicated-conventional-routes