# Razor Routing by calling a page with .cshtml ending

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Razor routes requests from "/mypage" to the file "mypage.cshtml"
But calling the web page via "/mypage.cshml" directly will not redirect to the file. Instead it will throw a 404 error.

Is it possible to configure this behaviour addtionally?
So that it is possible to call the mypage.cshtml file via

- /mypage
- /mypage.cshtml

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902581/11398810) resolve your issue?

Comment: looks simiiar, but does not work for razor pages. Seems to be for controller actions.

Comment: If you use Razor Pages,please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Custom model convention:

```
public class GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention: IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
        {
            var selector = model.Selectors[i];
            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Order = 1,
                    Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template+".cshtml",
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

2.Register `GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention` in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new GlobalTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());

    });
    //...
}
```

Result:

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-3.1#model-conventions