# How to add suffix on API Endpoints .NET Core

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core

Is there a way to automatically add a suffix on all endpoint routes e.g .json.

```
v1/users.json
v1/users/{id}.json
```

so what I have tried so far is I created a BaseController which look like this

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller].json")]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

but every time I use it to my controller it looks like this

```
v1/users.json
v1/users.json/{id}
```

Comment: parameters are passed to the controller actions. so `{id}.json` should be mapped to a controller action and not to the controller.

Comment: @Chetan so needed to add on each actions always? Is there a route config feature that could like add it as suffix always?

Comment: You could maybe use the rewrite middleware to accept `.json` on all endpoints but drop it during routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: how about [routes.MapRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902581/1518100)

Comment: Ill take a look first on what you guys suggested. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the URL Rewriting Middleware to accept URLs with .json and then simply remove it. So something like:

```
/api/users/123/picture.json?query=123
```

would become:

```
/api/users/123/picture?query=123
```

You can do this by adding the following code to your Startup's `Configure` method:

```
var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^(.*?)(?:\.json)(\?.*)?$", "$1$2");
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for more information.

Caveat: If you use `Url.Action(...)`, etc. to generate a URL within code, then it won't include `.json`. The rewrite only affects incoming requests.

Comment: Is there way to force the endpoints to have .json and return not found if it doesnt?

Comment: @Carlo You could add a rewrite on `^(?!.*?\.json)` (this should come above the `.AddRewrite` I added above) to redirect to a non-existent endpoint, or perhaps create a custom `IRule` implementation that returns a 404 result in that case.

Comment: I tried what you have above, but seems to be not working.

https://localhost:5001/v1/users - working
https://localhost:5001/v1/users.json - not working

Comment: @Carlo The order in which you apply middleware to the pipeline matters. If you put it below `app.UseRouting();`, for example, it won't work becauses routing has already occurred before it runs.

Comment: You'll also want it before `app.UseStaticFiles();` so that the static file middleware doesn't try and serve the request.

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra routing to the actual endpoints rather than the controllers

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/[controller]")]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(".json")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
    
    }
    
    // Without Route Parameters
    [HttpGet("{id}.json")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] int id)
    {
          ...
    }

    // With Route and Query Parameters
    [HttpGet("{id}.json/friend")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]int id,[FromQuery] string friendName)
    {
          ...
    }

    // With Route and Query Parameters and Body
    [HttpPost("{id}.json/friends")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromRoute]int id,[FromQuery] string message, [FromBody]IFilter filter)
    {
          ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can say this is a way to do it. But what if you have query parameters on get endpoints?

Comment: @Carlo Then you could end up with something like `/v1/base/123.json?abc=6`

Comment: @CarloLuisito I've updated the answer and it shows how to do QueryParams, Route Params and Body Params all in one rquest.

Comment: Im thinking the problem too is .json still needs to be added on specific endpoints that belong only to a specific controller?